# How do I get proper parameter names in cgo exported functions?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm writing a library in Go that I want to export to a c-shared-library. It works just fine, however i find it a little annoying that the exported header uses `p0`, `p1`, `p2`, `...` for parameter names instead of the original parameter names from Go. Is there a way to change this behavior or am I simply stuck with that?

> I am using `go version go1.12.7 darwin/amd64`

Example:

```
package main

/*
#import <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {}

//export MyFunc
func MyFunc(input *C.char) {
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(input));
}
```

```
go build -o libout.so -buildmode=c-shared
```

Output:

```
extern void MyFunc(char* p0);
```

Why isn't `p0` named `input`?

According to [this cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go), i should be getting variable names.

**It States**

> Go functions can be exported for use by C code in the following way:
>
> ```
> //export MyFunction
> func MyFunction(arg1, arg2 int, arg3 string) int64 {...}
>
> //export MyFunction2
> func MyFunction2(arg1, arg2 int, arg3 string) (int64, *C.char) {...}
> ```
>
> They will be available in the C code as:
>
> ```
> extern int64 MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2, GoString arg3);
> extern struct MyFunction2_return MyFunction2(int arg1, int arg2, GoString arg3);
> ```

However, when I compile that exact code it gave, i get this result:

```
extern GoInt64 MyFunction(GoInt p0, GoInt p1, GoString p2);
extern struct MyFunction2_return MyFunction2(GoInt p0, GoInt p1, GoString p2);
```

Why don't the parameters have their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go allows arbitrary rune names, e.g., instead of `input` you might call the variable `π`.  C does not allow such names.  Presumably the cgo authors didn't want to restrict your names, so they just renamed everything.

Curiously, [the documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go) implies that the generated code will use your names.  It would be nice if it did do that, provided that your names are viable.

Comment: I have a feeling this may only happen to pointers, but i could be wrong. I'm not home to test it right now.

Comment: I've verified it's not due to pointers. See my updated question.

Comment: I created a PR for Go that was accepted a few months ago and resolves this issue. It is slated for the go1.15 release sometime in August I believe. The related CL can be seen here: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/222619

Comment: @NathanF.: nice! I might have suggested using `_p%d` for the auto-generated names in case someone calls one parameter `p2` and another one `π` or something, but presumably they'll figure that out on their own and stop using `p%d` names :-)