# Avoid empty line in cgo exported function documentation

Tags: go, cgo

I'm writing a library in Go that I'm compiling to a native library using CGo, however when the functions are exported they have this annoying empty line between the function declaration and the documentation comment.

As an example, let's say I have this in my go file

```golang
/**
 * Prints an integer.
 *
 * @param p0 an integer to print.
 */
//export PrintInteger
func PrintInteger(val C.int) {
    fmt.Printf("%v", val);
}
```

Once it's exported in my C header file, it looks like this

```c
/**
 * Prints an integer.
 *
 * @param p0 an integer to print.
 */

extern void PrintInteger(int p0);
```

That empty line for the most part isn't a problem, but on some IDEs when parsing that header file they have difficulty properly displaying the intellisense, making consumption of the header slightly more difficult. Especially when you factor in the way that cgo [renames function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511799/how-do-i-get-proper-parameter-names-in-cgo-exported-functions)

Is there any way to avoid it without manually modifying the header file after it's been generated?

*Edit:*

I've found *what i believe* is the area in the go source code that causes this:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/cgo/out.go#L922

Comment: Other than fixing the code you've identified (to remove the extra newline), I think the answer is no, you can't. I experimented a bit with trying to make the prefix block comment not end with a newline and that just causes the function not to be exported at all. (It should be easy to automate an update of the generated header files, though: just look for a block comment end sequence, followed by a blank line, followed by `^extern .*);$`, and remove the blank line.)

Comment: I ended up making the pull request myself. It was just merged in this afternoon so this should finally not be a thing pretty soon. https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/222419/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this should be included in go 1.15.

https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/222419/